# How to stretch a div vertically to the footer, and stretch to fit content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to make a div stretch down to my footer, with limited success. I've tried using jQuery to do this but it has some issues:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){

$(window).resize(function(){
var height = $(this).height() - $("#banner-wrapper").height() - $("#footer-wrapper").height()
$('#content').height(height);

})

$(window).resize(); //on page load

});//]]>  

</script>
```

This stretches the div down to the footer, but the problem is, it bases the height of of the **window size.** If your content extends past the fold, the #content div doesn't stretch to fit the content.

[http://matthewdail.com/staging/](http://www.matthewdail.com/staging/)
Here you can see the jQuery doing it's job and stretching the #content div perfectly, but it doesn't extend to fit the content.

I've also tried some of the more common css tricks like:

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}

#content{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto -120px;
float:none;
min-height:100%;
height:auto !important;
height:100%;
}
```

I've searched everywhere but can't find a solution to this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `layout` and see if it works for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/14/

I have updated the fiddle to make the layout something similar to what you have,
http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/16/

hope this helps

edit: Make sure all the columns are of the same height
http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/21

Comment: @user2581300, if you have any questions let me know

Comment: This is almost perfect. But when you fill col2 with content that goes past the fold, col1 and col3 shrink down.  
[http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/20/](http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/20/)  
I don't think this will cause me a problem though, as these columns won't have content in them. But I thought you might want to know.

Comment: @user2581300  I dont like almost perfect thing, here you go http://jsfiddle.net/TCdsK/21/, edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the content div to extend down so that it pushes the footer to the bottom of the window? You'd be better off [using something like this](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/):

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If the body doesn't contain enough content the footer will still stay at the bottom. [Demo here](http://mystrd.at/data/sticky_footer.html).